# Transaction shows up as sent, but was never recieved

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core

I sent 0.002 BTC to 15bPd9YSB3kpuAFFz2tBZh39A3XdnN5UoX (I paid the transaction fee), but Bitcoin-Qt crashed when I pressed send. When I reopened it the transaction showed up, but it isn't in Blockexplorer.com or Blockchain.info or the reciving client. I tried rescanning both the sending and recieving clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to run getrawtransaction on the transaction ID (from the transaction list) then run sendrawtransaction on the result.